# Why is the exit loss $\frac{u^2}{2g}$ is small for laminar flow?

Tags: fluid-mechanics

[image]

I have done some calculations:

[image]

My lecturer just said that exit loss $\frac{u^2}{2g}$ is small for laminar flow so ignore it. But never explains why it is small?

Comment: So calculate the velocity then work out that term...

Comment: @SolarMike then show me......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption that the velocity head is small is due to velocities in laminar flow generally being low. This assumption is supported by the observation that laminar flow is more commonly seen in smaller diameter systems where high velocities are typically kept low to keep the frictional losses low. Recall that Reynolds number is directly proportional to velocity and the diameter in pipe flow calculations.